# Search for application like cheese, where i can take webcam photo and copy it directly to clipboard

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam, clipboard, cheese, photo

I Search for an application like cheese, where I can take webcam photo. But it should be able to copy it directly to my clipboard. Thank you. I have ubuntu 20.04.

EDIT:
I will explain it more on detail:

When I make a photo screenshot, I am able to copy the screenshot instantly and to put it somewhere else. Just with clicking on copy or Ctrl+C.

When I make a photo with my webcam, I have to
save the picture first somewhere in a folder,
than search the picture,
than copy it,
go back to the place where I want to have the picture and
than paste it.

I'm searching for a "webcam software" with the opportunity, to copy the file just after I took a photo with my webcam, without saving it to specific folder, searching it and so on.

For a better understanding, I made a short video of my workflow with "screenshots" compared to the workflow, when i have to take a webcam picture:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sEorlqLsqjwqYcAtEWNPuD1tHSQj_X6Y/view

It would be great if someone know a programm, where the workflow to paste pictures, which are taken through webcam, can be pasted faster.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Even better works with flameshot: https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot

---

Okay, one possible solution I found (late, but nevertheless):

1. Don't make a screenshot with the Camera. Just open it.
2. Install flameshot (sudo apt-get install flameshot)
3. Set up a shortcut for flameshot gui. For example in LxQt: in LxQt konfiguration under Shortcuts. Set a new shortcut (for example Ctrl + Space). The executed command after Ctrl + Space should be "flameshot gui". Where to set shortcuts can differ, please take a look where to set it in KDE / GNOME and so on.
4. Now open the cam application of your choice. In the cam view you will see the actual screen. Hit ctrl + space to capture the screen and select the part of which you want to have a photo.
5. Press ctrl + C to copy the image.

I am sure you can also combine the command of "open webcam" (just look in your processes how to know how to start your webcam application), then sleep e.g. 1 second and then execute flameshot gui.

I know it's not a solution to copy directly from an webcam image - but the result is the same - you can copy the screen of your webcam directly to your clipboard, without temporary saving the picture.

Sorry for the late answer, but maybe it helps someone else in the future.